# MVC Form - Restrict fields in a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I hide fields in a MVC form for a specific user?

I have 2 types of users and I want one of them to have access to the complete form but the other should only access some fields.

Comment: conditionally render form fields using an `if` block ?. Remember hiding is not restricting.  You should not render the form element at all

Comment: I'd even consider a single page that loads separate partial views based on the user type

Comment: Plus, your logic that processes the data needs to do the necessary validation as well - because anyone can send _any_ data to your site.

Comment: you can render or not based on user role

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below can be used to hide or show a section of html depending on a user's role assignment.  See [Role Identity](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97) about implementing roles in MVC.
I used the code below to apply a label depending on what role a user belongs to.  It can also be used for hiding fields.

```
   @if (this.User.IsInRole("ProjectManager"))
    {
       <div id="rolelabel" class="text-muted text-xs" style="color:white;">
        Project Manager
       </div>
    }

   @if (this.User.IsInRole("Developer"))
    {
       <div id="rolelabel" class="text-muted text-xs" style="color:white;">
        Developer
       </div>
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.